# How to get the date of birth from the calender in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-calendar

I am new in android.
My layout is as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="26-01-2010" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calender" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a Edit Box and button. When I click on the Button, I want to open a calender and be able to pick a date from calender. Also, the selected date has to be set to the Edit Box.

Comment: use a DatePicker, that's what it is for.

Comment: show your code which you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call method SelectDate on textview or button or editext click

```
 private void SelectDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:

            // open datepicker dialog.
            // set date picker for current date
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year  = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day   = selectedDay;

        // Show selected date
        birthdate_edt.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Dialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            yourEditText.setText(String.format("%02d.%02d.%04d", day, month+1, year);
         }
      }
   }
});
```

you may also set your edittext not focusable to prevent manual value entering

Comment: Thanks Serejja,  It not give me calender, Please give me right way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

***I did this and it worked for me!***

**Method for opening a pop-up DatePickerDialog**

```
public void openDatePickerDialog(final View v) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Get Current Date
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                String selectedDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.editTextDob:
                        ((EditText)v).setText(selectedDate);
                        dob = selectedDate;
                        Log.e("DOB selected",dob);
                        break;
                }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

**Then simply call the method above onClick listener insider onCreateActivity**

```
edtDOB.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                openDatePickerDialog(view);
            }
        }
    });
edtDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
```